# How to fix Unsupported field value error in angular firestore?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-storage, angularfire2

Following is the code for pushing images to fire storage.

```
item.images.forEach((image) => {
  this.pushImage(image, `items/${this.itemId}/images/`);
});
```

And

```
  pushImage(image, basePath) {
    const imgId = returnRandStr();
    const route = `${basePath}${imgId}`;
    const imageRef = this.angularFireStorage.ref(route);

    return concat(
      imageRef.put(image)
        .snapshotChanges().pipe(ignoreElements()),
      defer(() => imageRef.getDownloadURL())
    ).toPromise()
  }
```

The image object has the following form

```
File {
  lastModified: 1604278838065
  lastModifiedDate: xxx
  name: "image_test.jpeg"
  size: 131560
  type: "image/jpeg"
  webkitRelativePath: ""
}
```

So the images is an array.

But the issue is that I'm getting the following error:

> vendor.js:16168 ERROR FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom File object

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFN0d.png)

**NOTE** note that if I push the image to storage without storing it inside an array (ie. as soon as I receive the $event.target.files[0] directly), then I won't receive this error message. But when I store the image inside an array and loop through the array and perform push function for each image then this error is throw. (seems like storing the image file is causing the issue, but I've double checked it before the pushing, it is still the same File {} object.)

NOTE THAT EVEN THOUGH THIS ERROR IS THROWN THE IMAGE IS GETTIN UPLOADED TO FIRESTORAGE. && Also I'm receiving back the resolved image download url.

so how can I prevent this exception. I've checked the image object before it is pushed to fire storage (it is still the same File {} object). Not sure what is happening when I store it inside an array!!

Answer (score 0):

It says: "Unsupported field value: a custom File object". Firebase doesn't support class instance object when you set, add a document.
To remove this error, convert your file object to a pure js object by doing so:

```js
const file = new file();
docRef.set(Object.assign({}, file));
```

In your code, I think the error triggers when you call the put method, because your image is a File object:

```js
...
return concat(
      imageRef.put(Object.assign({}, image))
        .snapshotChanges().pipe(ignoreElements()),
      defer(() => imageRef.getDownloadURL())
    ).toPromise()
...
```

Or try to find a docRef.set() or docRef.add() call in your code with a class instance object as a param.